# Chrome Extension won't appear by filtering in the Web Store, only by search

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

This has bothered me for a long time, and there is no way to contact Google for support, and their documentation doesn't cover this.

I think I must be missing something, but I can't for the life of me figure it out

If you search for my extension manually, it shows up:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/mortality

but if you just go to the store and apply the relevant filters 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions

Extensions, Productivity, Runs Offline

It doesn't show up.

I have had it in the store for a few months now, initially I had thought it just takes some time to show up but I now am fairly confident I'm missing something.

The manifest is correct (Compared to other apps that do show)
Region and language is correct

Has anybody seen this before, and know what the problem is?

Comment: none will reply...even on google group. The only thing you can do is wait, not the times described, for example, I've waited a week before seeing my simple manifest public

Comment: i've never used google groups but i have been on the site and that's a good idea-- i'll ask that community.  And like I said in my question, it's been a few months

Comment: You can contact the CWS dev support team at https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/ to get a human to look at your issue. They usually have a quick response rate. If you receive a useful reply, it would be nice to post the relevant part as an answer to your own question, as it may help others.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've met this issue before and have contacted with the CWS dev support team. It is because chrome web store doesn't list the item under its category if it has already been installed by the user. I can see your extension under "Extensions, Productivity, Runs Offline" category properly since I didn't install your extension. I think Google CWS team is considering to show up the item under its category no matter if the user has installed it in the future.

Comment: Wow.  that's it.  Thank you!

I was so confused haha.  I tried it on all of my machines and it still didn't work-- even in incognito mode.  Didn't even realize that I am signed in chrome in all of my machines so that explains it.  Wasted way too much time trying to troubleshoot this -.-

Answer (score -1):

CWS works strange, I think some unwanted to Google extensions and apps are blocked and are not shown in the top of categories. You can check this by going to the bottom of the categories and see these unwanted apps and extensions. Simple set the filter to 4 stars and you can find this apps in the place when apps and extensions with promotion tales ended.

Comment: All due respect, this is more a comment than an answer.